# Tensorflow Serving docker: No versions of servable colbert founder under base path /models/model

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I can't find the right command to launch tensorflow serving. My model is in a directory called colbert, in this directory you have: `saved_model.pb` another directory called `variables`. The directory colbert is at `/home/ubuntu`

I tried the following to launch tensorflow serving: `sudo docker run -p 8501:8501 --mount type=bind,source=/home/ubuntu/colbert/,target=/models/colbert/ -e MODEL_NAME=colbert -t tensorflow/serving` but I have the title message, any idea what I did wrong? thanks!

The doc: https://towardsdatascience.com/serving-keras-models-locally-using-tensorflow-serving-tf-2-x-8bb8474c304e

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow serving expects a version, so just needed to add a directory with name 1 and it made the trick!